# Is it more or less efficient to perform a check before performing a Replace in C#?

Tags: c#, text, replace

This is an almost academic question but I'm curious as to its answer.

Suppose you have a loop that performs a routine replace on every row in a dataset. Let's say there's 10,000 such rows.

Is it more efficient to have something like this:

```
 Row = Row.Replace('X', 'Y');
```

Or to check whether the row even contains the character that is to be replaced in the first place, like this:

```
 if (Row.Contains('X')) Row = Row.Replace('X', 'Y');
```

Is there any difference in terms of efficiency? I realize that that the difference might be very minor bit I'm interested in knowing if one way is better than the other regardless of how much better it may be. Also, would your answer be different if the probability of finding the character that's to be replaced was 10% from it it being 90%?

Comment: What's the type of `Row`? string? I see no reason why the second should ever be faster unless the setter of `Row` is very expensive. And in that case you could first store the result in a local variable, check if it's different from before and only then assign to `Row`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your check, `Row.Contains('X')`, is an O(n) function, which means that it iterates over the entire string one character at a time to see if that character exists.

`Row.Replace('X', 'Y')` works exactly the same way, it checks every single character one character at a time.

So, if you have that check in place, you iterate over the string potentially twice. If you just replace, you iterate over the string once.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the check was already built into the Replace function and you've just confirmed it. This clearly means that doing becomes redundant and answers my question.

Comment: Also, there are other things to consider - how many string objects are created and therefore impact of garbage collection etc. Best thing is to not try and optimise in one's head - run the code, measure it, and make targeted performance improvements where they are found to be required.

Comment: In this particular case, there is nothing else to consider and there are no extra objects created - the call to Replace will always perform a check for Contains, so it is unnecessarily to do so prior to that call. That answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to measure first on a realistic dataset, then decide which is higher performance. If your typical dataset doesn't often have anything, then having the `Contains()` call may be faster (because although `Replace` also iterates through all chars in the string, there will be an extra string object created and garbage collected due to the immutability of strings), but if "X" is often present, the check becomes a waste and actually slows things down.

Also, this typically isn't the first place to look for and worry about performance problems. Things like chatty interfaces, network I/O, web services, databases, file I/O and GUI updates are going to hurt you orders of magnitude more than stuff like this.

If you were going to do stuff like this, and if `Row` came back from a database (as it's name suggests) then getting the database to do the query *might* be another approach to save performance. E.g.

```
select MyTextColumn from MyTable where MyTextColumn like '%X%'
```

Then perform the replacement on all the results, because you know you only returned results where the replacement was needed.

This does introduce other concerns though - for example, in SQL Server, if the above example included an index on `MyTextColumn`, SQL Server won't be able to use that index because the `like` argument starts with a wildcard (it's not considered to be "sargable").

In summary, *write for correctness, readability and maintenance first, then measure performance and make targeted improvements where they are found to be required*.

Comment: Thank you. What if I was doing a replace not on a dataset but a primitive string variable, would one way be consistently better than the other one then?

Comment: "In summary, write for readability and maintenance first, then measure performance and make targeted improvements where they are found to be required." I agree with that. The question behind my question was a more mathematical one, I guess - however, it seems that because every call to Replace already contains a check like the one I presented in the second case, then that check is not needed. Thanks!

Comment: No one way would be **consistently** better than another in all situations. You need to write your code to be functionally correct and readable and **only then** can you run it, take measurements and make appropriate performance improvements if any are necessary.

Comment: "No one way would be consistently better than another in all situations." That may be so but that doesn't mean that one way cannot consistently be worse than all others. And, in this case, it seems like the second way is just that.

Comment: I think I've not made my point well enough if you think that. The point is - *prove it*...

Comment: Prove what? That it's possible to have one one way of doing things that's always ineffeicient? I think we are talking about different thing at this point, Neil. I also think you are overgeneralizing what was a very specific question.

Comment: Man, you don't get it. Sure, you could find a way that is very inefficient - write it all out to a file on a remote drive over WCF on the internet to a server in another continent - that will be slower. But my point is that when you get two *similar* solutions, and can't quite tell, and need to ask on StackOverflow.com, you need to actually benchmark and test and prove which solution is quicker. Have you never heard of "premature optimisation"?

Comment: Neil, I think the problem is that you are not getting the question I was asking, at all. What's more, you seem to have an issue with me pointing it out. There is nothing stranger than seeing someone make a comment like that in a question that's already been answered. Take my word for it, you may think you know why I asked the question I asked but you are thinking in more general terms to a point where the question loses all meaning.

Comment: What's more, and I mean to imply any disrespect but it is you who seem to be lacking some knowledge related to optimization - as demonstrated by the fact that not everything needs to be benchmarked - in this particular case (which is far less extreme than the WCF example you presented) it can be shown that the call to contains is ALWAYS going to be slower because REPLACE already contains a call to it. Which, is, really, all I wanted to confirm in the first place. If it's ok with you I would like to reserve the right to define the scope of my questions and I would also like end this discussion.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. I was trying to illustrate the dangers of theory over practice, given most people lack detailed knowledge of the implementation of classes in the CLR. If that point is not relevant to your question, I shan't argue further. I did check your example, and found the version with `Contains()` *is* slower, you'll be pleased to hear. I wouldn't *normally* expect the implementation in the CLR to change enough to change the results (though of course they reserve the right to in future versions), and I guess whatever Mono does is the same. Though, of course, I'd check to be sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first option is faster. In order to check if a substring is present it first has to find it. As there won't be any caching mechanism why not replace it directly? Otherwise you'd be searching twice. If 'X' is present many times you would be basically doubling the effort.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that strings in C# are IMMUTABLE. That means they cannot change.

For it to replace anything it has to create a new string in memory, and copy the data across, then garbage collect the old string later on.

Using Contains() first, will prevent needless creation, copying, and garbage collection of string data, and therefore perform faster.

Comment: Why would `Replace` create a new string if it does not replace anything?

Comment: This is incorrect info; in .Net `String`s are not copied when changed, but build together with pointers. So without a change, it's certainly not coping the data. Source 'Visual Basic .NET Text Manipulation Handbook: String Handling and Regular Expressions'